# NSDataAsset() only returning one json file when there are 2 specified

Tags: ios, json, swift, assets

I'm trying to read multiple files from the `data` section of a Data asset. I'm currently prototyping and writing json files directly into the Asset Bundle folders, under a folder called "CommonData.dataset". CommonData is properly set up as a `Data set` within my assets catalogue.

It all works fine, EXCEPT I only ever get data for one json file, even 'tho I've listed 2 files in the data section of Contents.json, which is documented as an array of entries:

```
{
  "data" : [
      {
          "filename" : "ATestFile.json",
          "idiom" : "universal",
          "universal-type-identifier" : "public.json"
      },
      {
          "filename" : "AnotherTestFile.json",
          "idiom" : "universal",
          "universal-type-identifier" : "public.json"
      }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "author" : "xcode",
    "version" : 1
  }
}
```

After this call, asset.data only contains the contents of the first file, the second never even gets read:

```
let asset = NSDataAsset(name: "CommonData", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

In my production code I'll have 30 or 40 json files referenced, concatenating them isn't an option. I'm sure I'm missing something simple - is there an iterator or a cast I can use, or do I need to do multiple calls to NSDataAsset?

The json for both referenced files is well formed BTW, this isn't a stray comma issue (unfortunately).

Comment: "After this call" After what call? You have not shown any code making any call. Could you show us what you're doing? Keep in mind that your job is to help us _reproduce_ the issue.

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear, the 'after this call' refers to the code after the colon (let asset = NSDataAsset(name: "CommonData", bundle: Bundle.main)) - asset!.data only contains data for the first file referenced in Contents.json, which you can tell if you check the buffer length. I removed all the other code because I have established that this is the statement that is failing.

Comment: Well, I guess what I meant was, it sounds like you are munging the asset catalog's underlying contents directly. How are you doing that?

Comment: Ah, ok, just writing the json directly (by hand for this exercise). Looking at Eugene Dudnyk's answer it sounds like I'm trying to use the array for something it's not intended for.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed you had this automated in some way. I think the answer is that automating it is what you _need_ to do. :) I'm pretty there are tools to help you with this but it's just elementary scripting, I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is there in asset json format in order to accommodate for different traits. I.e. you can have in data array two file descriptions, one for light mode, and one for dark mode, etc. You can not have access to more than one file description with the same traits, simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, looks like I'm trying to bend it. I'll find another solution.